# What is two photon interference?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics

I already had a question about the Hanbury Brown Twiss effect, but this question is actually a seperatre question:

[Here](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-017-02408-6) I red following:

> The HBT effect comes from the interference of different but
> indistinguishable two-photon probability amplitudes22,23,24. If these
> two ways are distinguishable, even in principle, there will be no
> two-photon interference. Thus, no HBT effect should be observed4.

Why is this so. I think I understand the two photon interference a bit. In case of the HBT effect, where we use a beam splitter, we get following picture:
[image]
So, in case of indistinguishable bosons, A and C will cancel each other.
Otherwise they wont. But how is this now connected to the HBT effect. For me the HBT effect is just due to statictics?

Comment: Your link is incorrect.

Comment: Perhaps you are confusing the current situation with the Hong-Ou-Mandel effect. However, in that case the two photons enter from different ports. Here, in case the photons are indistinguishable, the cases for A and C should be identical. Hence, no sign change. Hence, no cancellation.

Comment: @flippiefanus How is this connected to HBT effect - do you have any literature

Comment: The HOM effect is a quantum interference effect. HBT, on the other hand, can be purely based on classical intensity correlations. So, they are not really related.

Comment: Also I think the orientation of the beamsplitter in the image you provided seems to be incorrect. The interface should probably be along the other diagonal.

Comment: @flippiefanus I still have difficulties to understand: May you have a look on the following. Why is the time average of two intensities <n(n-1)>  https://youtu.be/HxVXZxe75lA?t=438

Comment: This sounds like a different question that is not directly related to the original question. Perhaps you should post it as a separate question. Then you can provide enough information so that people can understand your question.